# Which preposition(by or with) will be used?

Tags: prepositions, by-with

"I am struck with flu" or "I am struck by flu"
Which is the correct sentence?

Comment: Struck by flu symptoms, flu-struck, flu has struck me!!

Comment: @Josh61 : could you provide any reference to the 'struck 'by' usage. It's incorrect .

Comment: http://www.smh.com.au/fifa-world-cup-2014/world-cup-news-2014/world-cup-2014-seven-german-players-struck-by-flu-coach-says-20140704-zsvdb.html

Comment: As a more general usage, *struck by* appears to be a more common expression than *struck with* :https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=struck+by%2C+struck+with&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cstruck%20by%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cstruck%20with%3B%2Cc0

Comment: As for *flu* I think both expressions are acceptable.

Answer (score 2):

You can say

- I **was struck by** [the] flu.
    (simple past tense—you might have recovered already)

But

- I **am stricken with** [the] flu.
  (past participle as predicate modifier—you currently have the flu, and are feeling horrible)

Of course, if you didn't want to sound so **melodramatic**, you could say:

- I am down with the flu 
  (confined—mostly—to bed)
- I am fighting the flu
  (struggling, but probably not confined to bed—maybe even working, but suffering some symptoms)
- I have the flu
  (no indication of severity)
- I caught the flu
  (no indication of severity, nor of whether you have recovered)

Comment: This is a good answer, why has someone downvoted it? I upvoted so that it could come back to normal.

Comment: Thank you. An upvote actually counts 5x as much as a downvote (+10 vs -2).

Comment: All the answers have been downvoted. Beats me why.

Answer (score 0):

'I am struck with flu' is the correct sentence.

'I am struck by flu' is wrong.

For reference : http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/struck has a similar example for it.

Comment: I followed your link, but found no examples of "struck with" or "struck by".

Comment: @BrianHitchcock : do you know Ctrl + F .. find 'struck with' in it in the page

Comment: Well, that was a pain to find. For the record, you have to scroll down to _British dictionary definitions for struck_, then expand the verb section, and then you’ll find it as definition 16. Simply searching on the page will not find it, since the element that contains the quote is hidden. You should always include the quotes you refer to when linking to a different site.

Comment: In addition, _struck by flu_ is not wrong. A simple Google search of “struck by flu” and “struck with flu” yields (for me) about 4,000 hits for _by_ and only 85 hits for _with_, which is a good indicator of which version is more common.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet : I suggest you look at the question first! He is asking the usage with 'I am' not in general. When did you ever use the sentence : I am struck down by flu?

Comment: Personally, I have never used that sentence (the _down_ is also not there in the question). I have also never used, nor heard anyone else use, the sentence “I am struck with flu”. The verb _strike_ is not generally used in the passive in the first person singular with diseases at all—the normal phrasing is simply “I have the flu” or “I’ve got/caught [the] flu”. I have, however, heard people say about others, “He is struck by [the] flu”, and also “He is _stricken_ with [the] flu”, as Brian’s answer says.

Comment: @Veronica Diamond: thanks, but I have no Ctrl + F on my iPhone.

Comment: If you're struck *by* a baseball bat, there's no implication that somebody meant to hit you; if you're struck *with* a baseball bat, the implication is that somebody wanted to hurt you. There's (usually) no intention involved in catching the flu, so I would use *struck by flu*. People are often *struck by lightning*, [rarely](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=struck+by+lightning%2C+struck+with+lightning&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cstruck%20by%20lightning%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cstruck%20with%20lightning%3B%2Cc0) *struck with lightning*.

Answer (score -2):

"I am struck with flu" is correct answer because one can not be struck by some no-physical thing. Or we can also say "I am struck due to flu"

Comment: Of course you can be struck by a non-physical thing. You can be struck by grief, you can be struck by someone’s smile, etc. You **cannot**, however, be “struck due to flu”. That is not English.